# ag-grid sorting on cell value changed

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

values in my grid table can change at any time. I would like to keep it sorted after every value change in a sorted column. Is there any grid or column API I can call in onCellValueChanged event?

Regards

Comment: When you say 'at any time' are you talking about user input? or is it changing due to some sort of data stream?

Comment: Both of them, depending on column

Comment: I believe that `onCellValueChanged` is only called after editing, meaning that it will only be called after user input changes the value.

Comment: So there's no way?

Comment: Of course there is some way of doing it. However you will likely need two implementations, one to handle the data that is changed via user input and one for the data stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
gridOptions.api.setSortModel(gridOptions.api.getSortModel())
```

but this may be overkill - you can also get the state off the current column sort and apply that accordingly